# How to overcome access denied error in share point?

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint

This is the code, i am using this code to insert data in my list in share point. If user have permission then this code is inserting data into list.
If user dont have permission then it is raising error access denied . How to overcome this?

```
Protected Sub Btn_Registration_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As                                                      System.EventArgs) Handles Btn_Registration.Click
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(AddressOf TcregistrationRun)
End Sub
Public Sub TcregistrationRun()     
            Dim _TCNricNum As String = Session("IC").ToString
            Dim _Msite As SPSite = New SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url)
            Dim _MWeb As SPWeb = _Msite.OpenWeb("/Admin")
            _MWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = True              
            NewEnTry.Update()
            _MWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = False 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...create a new instance of the web and a new instance of the site inside of the call for running with elevated privileges.  This will ensure that you have a new instance under the higher privileges.  It should work if you allow anonymous access on your site.  See thread [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/59937fe2-64fe-4a0f-9cc6-176efd096b9c).  You need to also remember get an instance of the list in the method call.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID)) 
{ 
   using (SPWeb web = site.AllWebs[SPContext.Current.Web.ID]) 
   { 
      web.AllowUnsafeUpdate = true; 

      // Get instance of list item and set the values 

      // Call update on the list item

      web.AllowUnsafeUpdate = false;
   } 
}
```